# Blurry text on wxWidgets controls

Tags: windows, wxwidgets

I compiled one of the latest wxWidgets samples on MS Windows. 
On high DPI display with all setting default text and bitmaps are blurry and less clear comparing to other Windows apps?
Check [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eUbT.png)

Bitmaps probably not so much, but should fonts scale?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which operating system and which version of wxWidgets are you using? If it is MS Windows (which it looks like), then this is probably due to a high DPI display.

Comment: It's MS Windows. Yes, it's a high DPI display. But should fonts scale to accommodate resolution?  I downloaded latest wxWidgets from github. Other projects I checked like FileZilla look ok after compilation. I have to research why.

Comment: @olekb, most likely you need to update the Manifest file for the sample in question and enable the Hi-DPI there. This settings is not there by default as such screens are not default currently.

Comment: DPI virtualization is turned on by default, unless you [declare your app dpiAware](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms701681(v=vs.85).aspx) in the manifest or the winapi call.